# converting CodeIgniter language files to .po (for gettext)

Tags: php, codeigniter, internationalization, multilingual, gettext

I'd like to maintain my native language translation for a CodeIgniter-based application.

However, translation files are in app_lang.php file as content of the array, and I'd like to use 'standard' gettext tools to translate which are also easier to maintain, keep under DVCS etc.

Do you know about some application which would enable to convert from/to CodeIgniter language files to/from gettext *.po files?

All I know is the following blueprint at Launchpad: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/phsite/+spec/gnu-gettext-translations

Comment: Please include a link to a CodeIgniter "language file".

Comment: Here it is: https://bitbucket.org/jesseterry/myclientbase/src/8d5ae553787e/application/language/english/mcb_lang.php

Answer (score 0):

The multi-platform tool [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) allows you to perform customisable searches on your code and generate a .po file from the results. It's a bit buggy on OS X and I haven't tried it with CI language files, but have used it on custom internationalization code and it worked perfectly.

You will need to edit the rules to use `$this->CI->lang->line` or `$lang` but it should work after a little tweaking.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it, but wonder what to do about *.po ---> CI since the application is not using gettext() mechanism?

Comment: You can modify CI to use GETTEXT using the following two methods outlined on the Wiki: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Category:Internationalization::Gettext

Comment: Yeah, I know about it, butthe problem is that I'm not the owner of the project, but hust someone wanting to make it easier while doing translation and maintaining it.

Comment: Maybe the solution will be available when/if Transifex gets support for PHP fils.